# Population Pyramids in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a population pyramid in Excel. All the guides make it sound simple but my charts don't want to play nice.

When I select a 2D cluster chart it should come out looking like this by default
[image]

With Series 1 and Series 2 going in either direction from a central axis, but instead it bust displays them on top of one another like so
[image]

Every guide I read just assumes that the series will go in opposite directions from a central axis so I can't find a way to change it.

Comment: Have you tried to put all the "Females" data negative?

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked an important part of the guides that said one series must be negative to achieve the desired affect.